# Test whether a MetaTable refers to a table or a view

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

When using the LINQ-to-SQL MetaModel, how do I determine whether a given MetaTable refers to a table or a view?  For example, if you launch LINQPad, then open a new query and select a database, you can list all tables as MetaTable objects:

```
Mapping.GetTables()
```

LINQPad somehow knows which ones are tables and which ones are views.  How do I make this determination in my code?  Is this something MetaModel deliberately abstracts away?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the MetaTables from LINQ to SQL simply:

```
var db = new MyDataContext("...");
var tables = db.Mapping.GetTables();
```

There is nothing specific on the MetaTable object however that details whether something is a table or a view so unless you have a naming convention you're going to still be out of luck.